# Python - when saving data to an sqlite db, then restarting the machine, db is filled with zeros

Tags: python, bash, macos, sqlite, reboot

I have a python script that creates a sqlite db, saves it and closing the connection with `close()`.
Afterwards, I reboot my system (osx) with:

`subprocess.call(echo mypassword| sudo -S shutdown -r now, shell=True)`

What happens , is after the system is rebooted , some of the time (it's not consistent) the db is filled with one or two zeros fields instead of the fields I saved.
I tried things like , creating a bash script that will perform the shutdown (and calling it from python-instead of executing shutdown directly), and even call `killall python` before sending the shutdown command in the bash script, but it still didn't help.
For me , it seems like sometimes python keeps some open handles maybe to the db , although I close it correctly and although I can't see the db instance in the memory while using pycharm debugger (I know it doesn't mean the handle is really closed)

I don't know how to continue in solving this from here

Comment: Where is your sqlite saving the db file? Is it in a reboot-persistent directory?

Comment: If you haven't done a `connection.commit()` then a forced closure will rollback... So if you've got some things that are auto-commiting or explicitly commiting and others not... that might be it... but hard to say.

Comment: @JonClements  I am using `connection.commit()` before using `close()`

Comment: @AK47 the db file is in the same directory where the script I'm running is. Not sure what do you mean by "reboot persistent directory", can you please elaborate?